# Compound unique constraint with NULL values

Tags: postgresql, constraint, unique-constraint, check-constraints

With the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE favorite_comments(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   opinion_id BIGINT REFERENCES opinions(id),
   review_id BIGINT REFERENCES reviews(id),
   list_id INTEGER REFERENCES lists(id) NOT NULL
);
```

This are valid records (Review and opinion related to the same list):

```
id,  opinion_id,  review_id,  list_id
-------------------------------------
1,          333,       NULL,        4
2,         NULL,        444,        4
```

But i would like to prevent that same review or opinion can appear twice related to the same list:

```
id,  opinion_id,  review_id,  list_id
-------------------------------------
1,          333,       NULL,        4
2,         NULL,        444,        4
3,         NULL,        444,        4 <- WRONG
```

I would like to add a constraint that checks a conditional uniqueness, `UNIQUE(opinion_id, list_id) OR UNIQUE(review_id, list_id)`, but since `opinion_id`,`review_id` can be NULL im having some trouble with this

Ive tried this but does not work

`ALTER TABLE favorite_comments
ADD CONSTRAINT comments_can_only_be_saved_once_per_list
UNIQUE (opinion_id, review_id, list_id);`

Comment: I need to do some more checks but it seems to be working, but i really dont understand the logic behind since for example this `review_id= NULL, list_id = 4` its not going to be unique if you look this two columns in an isolated way.

Answer (score 7):

If you can identify a value that will never be stored in the referenced tables (e.g. a negative value), you can use a unique index that uses expressions:

```sql
create unique index 
  on favorite_comments( coalesce(opinion_id,-1), coalesce(review_id, -1), list_id );
```

the `coalesce()` will turn all null values in the same "real" value, forcing a unique constraint violation when you try to insert another NULL value.

The only drawback of a unique index compared to a unique constraint is, that the unique index can't be a target of a foreign key (while a unique constraint would be)

Comment: Very clever solution, its common to use this kind of "computed" constraints?

Comment: @ImanolY.: I don't know how "common" this is, but I have used it occasionally in Postgres and Oracle.